# Calculate amount of steps needed to navigate through a crawled website from one URL to another

Tags: mysql, data-structures, bigdata

Situation:
A single domain is crawled completely (Up to 10.000.000 URLs) and all URLs are saved into a MySql database table. Every URL is given a unique ID. All the Links between the URLs are saved in another Table. For example The URL with the `ID 1` links to the URL with the `ID 893`. One URL can link to n others, backlinks and loops are possible (`URL 1` Linking to `URL 6`. `URL 6` Linking to `URL 3`  and `URL 3` Linking back to `URL 1`). Because of the crawling nature every URL must have a path to the root URL.

My goal is to calculate the amount of steps required to get from the root level to a given URL. In the end I want to provide the information to the user that `URL 89` is 12 links away from the root level (shortest path found).

This problem has probably been solved before so is the a paper or even an example on how to solve this without bruteforcing it?

Comment: You want to calculate the shortest path in a graph, have a look at [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: this interests me and now I don't think I can make it thru the day without solving it:) Do you have any working test data available, obviously not the full works, with URLs disguised if needed as long as the links work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm:

```
Set root url distance to zero and others to null
Begin Loop  
Find urls matching the current distance  
Find their linked urls and if they are null set their distance to current + 1  
Increment current distance  
Loop if there are urls with distance not set yet
```

Have tested it with your data (942 urls, 27008 links) and got following results:

Shortest clicks from the start page:

```
Distance    Count
   0           1
   1         149
   2         600
   3         141
   4          38
   5           7
   6           6
```

Shortest clicks from/back to start page (uncomment the 3 lines UNION and SELECT):

```
Distance    Count
   0           1
   1         494
   2         447
```

I have put it on sql fiddle with a small amount of my own test data (had to use SQL Server as it only allows Select queries for MySQL).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efdd1/4

```
UPDATE crawl_urls SET Distance = NULL           -- Reset distances for the test
UPDATE crawl_urls SET Distance = 0              -- Start Root Url at 0 distance
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM crawl_urls)

DECLARE @UrlsToDo int = -1                      -- Count of Urls still to process
DECLARE @Distance int = 0                       -- Current Distance from root

WHILE (@UrlsToDo != 0)                          -- Loop while urls to process
BEGIN

 UPDATE crawl_urls                              -- Find urls at current distance
 SET Distance = @Distance + 1                   -- Set their linked urls distance
 WHERE Distance IS NULL AND ID IN (
   SELECT target_urls_id IDs FROM Links L1
   INNER JOIN crawl_urls A ON L1.crawl_urls_id = A.ID AND A.Distance = @Distance
 --UNION ALL                                    -- Union of both sides of link
 --  SELECT crawl_urls_id IDs FROM Links L2     -- Uncomment for shortest way BACK
 --  INNER JOIN crawl_urls B ON L2.target_urls_id = B.ID AND B.Distance = @Distance
 )

 SET @UrlsToDo = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM crawl_urls WHERE Distance IS NULL)
 SET @Distance = @Distance + 1

END                                             -- Increment Distance and loop

SELECT * FROM crawl_urls ORDER BY Distance      -- Output results
```

Things to note: You will need to make sure root url distance is 0 at the start. Also be aware that the loop could go indefinitely if there is an orphan url with no links to others, although this should not be possible in theory unless there were errors while crawling and records were skipped. Proper indexing will make a huge difference with bigger data sets.

I will be doing something almost identical to this soon and here are some other things I have noticed. There were 5% duplicates in the Links table and only allowing uniques would greatly speed things up - less records and better indexes. Also the home page has been added twice (with and without the '/' at end) so there will be a lot of extra duplicate links there in both directions, this may also apply to search friendly urls and folder names.